# Right way to add standard receptacle to this GFCI circuit

Tags: wiring, gfci

I've read [Can I add a standard receptacle on a GFCI circuit](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/21318/can-i-add-a-standard-receptacle-on-a-gfci-circuito) and have a similar situation in that I need to add a receptacle to an existing GFCI circuit, but when I pulled the existing GFCI plug from the wall, it looks substantially different than the version described there.

What I have looks like this, with connections on both sides:

[image: first side]
[image: second side]

I suspect they're chained to a receptacle at the second vanity in this bathroom, but unfortunately it's across the room from where I need the new outlet to be (which is right underneath this one). What's the correct way to make this happen, short of calling in an electrician?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use twist-on wire connectors (or other approved connector), to create a "pigtail".

- Turn off the power.
- Remove the LOAD side wires from the GFCI.
- Using a twist-on wire connector, connect the white wire you removed from the GFCI with the white wire feeding your new receptacle and a short bit of the same size wire (6-8"  should do).
- Do the same with the black wires.
- Attach the bare ground wire from the new cable, with all the other grounds in the box.
- Connect the other ends of the short bit of wire to the appropriate screw terminals on the GFCI.
- Reinstall the GFCI.
- Turn on the power.

Comment: Worked like a champ, and nothing blew up or burned down. Thanks!