# Can interior and exterior lights be on the same circuit breaker?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

Can I put them on the same circuit or do I need separate circuits?

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time. Your second question is a duplicate of [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/21318/can-i-add-a-standard-receptacle-on-a-gfci-circuit) so I removed it

Answer (score 2):

Yes, interior and exterior lights can be on the same circuit. The same circuit breaker that works for my family room also works for my porch.

And yes, GFCI and non-GFCI can also be on the same circuit. Typically they recommend that the GFCI outlet is the first receptacle connected to a circuit so if it trips, it cuts off power to the rest of the circuit since current will not travel through the neutral to the other leads.